# Is there a way to use iteration inside an object in html in angular?

Tags: html, angular, indexing

Here's how my html code is looking:

```
<div *ngFor="let historyArticle of historyArticles; let i=index">
    <div [innerHTML]='historyArticle[i].fields.text | mdToHtml'></div>
</div>
```

I want to target the every object inside the historyArticle array. Writing {{i}} inside a div gives me the index number for each entry but I want to use that to target the correct text field in each entry

Comment: Should be `historyArticles[i]`, but why not just ditch the index and use `historyArticle`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the i index at all in this case. historyArticle itself is the object you want:

```
<div *ngFor="let historyArticle of historyArticles">
  <div [innerHTML]='historyArticle.fields.text | mdToHtml'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it worked out for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using `*ngFor` in Angular is basically looping through an array.

> So doing :

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.historyArticles.length; i++) {
  // do something e.g console.log(this.historyArticles[i].fields.text);
}
```

> Is pretty much the same as :

```
<div *ngFor="let historyArticle of historyArticles">
  <span>{{ historyArticle.fields.text }}</span>
</div>
```

Hope it helps you understand that in this case you don't need to use `i = index`

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```
<div *ngFor="let historyArticle of historyArticles; let i=index">
    <div>{{historyArticle[i].fields.text | mdToHtml}}</div>
</div>
```